# Hosting multiple websites in Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

We have 8 websites and 5 of them are small. I would like to host those 5 website in same instance but their ip must be same and static. I couldn't find a way how to allocate a static ip for each of them and how to host them in a single instance. They are PHP. Their db's are hosted in Google SQL.

Comment: Why do you need a static IP for each of the websites? If you have a different hostname for each website, your webserver can serve a difference site depending on the requested host. You can do this with [Apache virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/vhosts/), for example.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Google Compute Engine docs on static IP addresses](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances-and-network#assign_new_instance):

> An instance can have only one external IP address. If it already has an external IP address, you must first remove that address by deleting the old access configuration, then adding a new access configuration with the new external IP address.

That said, you don't need to have a separate static IP address per website—you can serve an arbitrary number of sites from a single VM by using a feature such as [Apache virtual hosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/vhosts/) which let you serve a different site depending on the hostname that is requested by the user.

Comment: any Admin panel like Cpanel available to do this task in GCE

Comment: @arvindwill — [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) is the management UI you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This can be possible using [Protocol Forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/protocol-forwarding/).

You can have different IP addresses for each website while using single Virtual Machine.

I had successfully hosted my 3 sites using method in past. If you need, I can write up a detail explanation on some blog.